# DateTimePicker Redux Form Field Problems

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I recently upgraded to `redux-form` v6, and my `material-ui` custom datetime picker stopped working. Here's what it looks like now:

```
class DateTimePicker extends React.Component {
  handleDateChanged(e, value) {
    let currentTime;
    if (this.props.dateField.value) {
      let currentValue = moment(this.props.dateField.value);
      currentTime = currentValue.subtract(currentValue.clone().startOf('day'));
    }
    let newValue = moment(value).startOf('day').add(currentTime || 0);
    this.props.dateField.onChange(newValue.toDate()); //this.refs.timePicker goes undefined when this line runs.
    this.refs.timePicker.openDialog();
  }
  handleTimeChanged(e, value) {
    return this.props.dateField.onChange(value); //This is called, but the value does not change.
  }
  formatDate(value) {
    return moment.tz(value, this.props.timezone).format('M/D/YY HH:mm zz');
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <span>
        <DatePicker
          value={this.props.dateField.value || null}
          autoOk={true}
          maxDate={new Date()}
          floatingLabelText="Change At"
          floatingLabelStyle={{pointerEvents: 'none'}}
          errorText={this.props.dateField.touched && this.props.dateField.error}
          formatDate={this.formatDate.bind(this)}
          onChange={this.handleDateChanged.bind(this)}
        />
        <TimePicker
          style={{display: 'none'}}
          value={this.props.dateField.value || null}
          format="24hr"
          hintText="Time"
          ref="timePicker"
          onChange={this.handleTimeChanged.bind(this)}
        />
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

And it's used in the form like so:

```
<Field
  name="changeAt"
  component={({input}) => {
    return <DateTimePicker dateField={input} timezone={this.props.driver.homeTerminal.timezone} />
  }}
/>
```

I'm having two distinct problems.

**First problem**: When I pick a day, `handleDateChanged` is called as expected. When the method starts, `this.refs.timePicker` refers to the time picker as expected. However, when the line above it is executed (`this.props.dateField.onChange(newValue.toDate())`), then refs are lost and  and `this.refs.timePicker` changes to `undefined`.

Each subsequent time time I pick a date, refs are not lost, and it works correctly.

**Second problem**: When I pick a time, `handleTimeChanged` is called which calls `this.props.dateField.onChange(value)` with the correct value; however the  value is not changed.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to this stuff so I don't know whether I'll be much use. But addressing the second problem: The only difference between my code and yours is that I'm doing`<DatePicker ... onChange={this.props.onChange} />`. Alternatively you could do

```
constructor(){this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)}
```

and then remove the bind in the render() method. The render method gets called every time the (props?) change and perhaps the issue is to do with this bind.

The docs on this: http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-rc.4/docs/faq/CustomComponent.md/

I'm also using a react element instead of using a component, and it comes out quite cleanly.

```
const DateInput = ({ input, label, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
<DateTimeField  onChange={input.onChange}  />
);
```

with

```
<Field name="date" component={DateInput} label="Date & Time Starting" />
```

The above is working, so perhaps you could try iterating from there and adding code until the problem is reproduced?

Answer (score 0):

Answer right at the bottom and work your way up to suit various implementations:

https://github.com/erikras/redux-form-material-ui/issues/37

It's wanting an object, more specifically a Date object.

`format={(value) => value === '' ? null : new Date(value)}`